Разница между неизменяемыми и динамическими константными буферами в Direct3D 11: оптимизация и использование
Какая разница между неизменяемыми константными буферами и динамическими в Direct3D 11, и нужно ли для каждой модели делать динамический буфер?
Я разрабатываю 3D-приложение с использованием Direct3D 11 и столкнулся с вопросом оптимизации использования константных буферов. В частности, я хочу понять, какая разница между неизменяемыми константными буферами (D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT) и динамическими (D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC), и нужно ли для каждой модели делать динамический буфер.
Контекст:

Я использую константные буферы для хранения матриц преобразования
(мировой, видовой, проекционной) и других параметров, которые могут
изменяться каждый кадр.
Я считаю, что изменение положения камеры также влияет на обновление
буфера, особенно если включен растеризатор в режиме CULL_BACK.

Вопросы:
Разница между неизменяемыми и динамическими буферами:
Какая разница между неизменяемыми константными буферами (D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT) и динамическими (D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC) с точки зрения производительности и использования?

В каких случаях лучше использовать динамические буферы, а в каких — неизменяемые?

Нужно ли для каждой модели делать динамический буфер?

Нужно ли для каждой модели в сцене делать отдельный динамический буфер, или можно использовать один общий буфер для всех моделей?

Как это влияет на производительность и организацию кода?

Изменение положения камеры и обновление буфера:

Верно ли, что изменение положения камеры также требует обновления
константного буфера?
Как это влияет на выбор между динамическими и неизменяемыми буферами?

Skybox и динамические буферы:

Нужен ли динамический буфер для skybox, если он статичен и не
изменяется?
Почему во многих примерах используют динамические буферы для skybox,
если он не изменяется?

Текст и динамические буферы:

Как лучше поступать с текстом в контексте использования динамических
буферов?
Нужно ли использовать динамические буферы для текстурных координат и
других параметров текста?

Цель:
Хочу оптимизировать использование константных буферов в своем приложении, чтобы обеспечить максимальную производительность и эффективность. Буду благодарен за разъяснения и примеры использования в различных сценариях.

D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT не подразумевает создания константных буферов. D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC не подразумевает создания неконстантных буферов, хотя этот флаг обычно (но не обязательно) используется как раз для константных буферов.

@user7860670 А теперь, выключи свои тупые отговорки и объясни нормально, без воды. Тот факт, что твой "гениальный" уровень — это нарисовать какой-то 2D куб, не делает тебя экспертом в жизни. Не надо говорить абстрактную чушь, вместо того чтобы дать хоть какой-то конкретный ответ или предложить решение.
